# Need to highlight a certain element in array plot in mathematica

Tags: arrays, plot, wolfram-mathematica

The array plot is constructed using a list. I want to mark the max intensity element with a red pointer. Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for

```
m = {{1, 0, 0, 0.3}, {2, 7, 0, 0.3}, {1, 0, 1, 0.7}};
ArrayPlot[m /. Last[Sort[Flatten[m]]] -> Red]
```

[image]